# Laravel pass url parameter from controller to route

Tags: laravel, url, routes

How can you pass a parameter from controller to route. For example, in my controller i want to redirect the user to a route and also attach ?userID=xyz to the route. How can I do it?
So in my controller

```
public function mymethod(){
  return route('getmydata', ['data'=> 1]);
}
```

I have a route named getmydata

```
Route::get('/data/{data}', function (Request $request, $data) {
    ...
})->name('getmydata');
```

How would i pass ?userID in my controller so my route can be /data/{data}?userID=xyz

Thanks

EDIT still not working:

My controller:

```
public function mymethod(){
  $userID = xyz;
  return route('getmydata', ['data'=> 1, 'userID' => $userID]);
}
```

And then in my route:

```
Route::get('/data/{data}/', function ($data, $userID) {
...
})->name('getmydata');
```

I'm getting

```
"Too few arguments to function App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider
```

I'm passing two parameters and expecting two. What am i missing?

the route should be /data/{data}?userID=xyz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameter from **controller** to **route** in this way :

```
return redirect()->route('getmydata', ['data'=> 1]);
// 127.0.0.1:8000/data/1
```

With `GET` parameter :

```
return redirect()->route('getmydata', ['data' => 1]);
// 127.0.0.1:8000/data?data=1
```

**Updated**  : If you want URL like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/{data}?userID=xyz`, then can do it by passing extra parameter with the route :

```
Route::get('/data/{data}', function (Request $request, $data) { ... })->name('getmydata');

return redirect()->route('getmydata', ['data'=> 1, 'userID' => 'xyz']);
// 127.0.0.1:8000/data/1?userID=xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass it on `queryparams` and retrieve them by `$request` object.

```php
Route::get('/data/{data}', function (Request $request, $data) {
    $userID = $request->userID; // or $request->get('userID')
})->name('getmydata');
```