# url parameter - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

our users access our site with a unique parameter on the url.  ie   `http://example.com/hire-agreement?u=unique_param`

I've set up a route to a view -

```
Route::get('/hire-agreement', function () {
    return view('hire-agreement');
});
```

I have 2 questions.

1. Do I need to add anything else to the Route to allow the parameter to be read in the view?
2. How do I read this parameter value in the View?  Can I use `$_GET["name"])` ?

thanks
Craig.

Comment: I think your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64351235/4575350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need anything more in the url section. and to use or get url parameter use laravel [request()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request) helper.

```
$value = request('key');
```

in view you can print a key like

```
{{ request('name') }}
```

complete example for you using request helper

```
Route::get('/hire-agreement', function () {
    $name = request('name'); //put the key in a variable
    return view('hire-agreement', compact('name')); //send the variable to the view
});
```

and then in view you can use the variable as

```
{{ $name }}
```

if you don't want to use a variable you can use directly request helper in view

```
{{ request('name') }}
```

you can use Request class too.

```
Route::get('/hire-agreement', function (Request $request) {
    $name = $request->name;
    return view('hire-agreement', compact('name'));
});
```

however i would suggest you to use a controller. don't use closure in route file. u can't cache them when needed.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me where I would put the `$value = request('key');` I dont understand why I need this line?

Comment: this is just an example. you can use this in view as well as in controller. here i am just putting the request key in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

**`http://example.com/hire-agreement?u=unique_param`**

in laravel you can access both `post` and `get`  can be access by `Request` class instance or `request()` helper so you can do

with helper [request()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request)

```php
Route::get('/hire-agreement', function () {
    dd(request('u')) //  this getting from url ?u=unique_param this u param
    return view('hire-agreement');
});
```

with Class [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#accessing-the-request)
or

```php
Route::get('/hire-agreement', function (Request $request) {
    dd($request->u)) //  this getting from url ?u=unique_param this u param
    return view('hire-agreement');
});
```

here you can

Answer (score 2):

You better pass the request to a controller and handle it there, it's easier and cleaner that way.however if you want to got straight from route to view, you better use the below method.
put this in your route file

```
Route::get('/hire-agreement/{param}', function ($param) {
    return view('hire-agreement')->with($param);
});
```

in the view you can access the param like this

```
<p>{{$param}}</p>
```

now if user request "/hire-agreement/1234" your $param in the view will contain 1234, Also if you would like to access get parameters in the url you can do it like this

```
{{Request::input('q')}}
```